# Django Unique Together Combination

Tags: python, django, django-models

My scenario is this:

```
class Partnership(models.Model):
    partner_a = models.ForeignKey(
        "Person", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='%(class)s_partner_a',
    )
    partner_b = models.ForeignKey(
        "Person", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='%(class)s_partner_b',
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (partner_a, partner_b)
```

This works just fine at refusing a duplicate partnership if a=a and b=b:
Ex:

```
>>> a = Person('a')
>>> b = Person('b')
>>> Partnership.objects.create(person_a=a, person_b=b)
>>> Partnership.objects.create(person_a=a, person_b=b) # IntegretyError as expected
```

However, it does not correctly refuse the following

```
>>> a = Person('a')
>>> b = Person('b')
>>> Partnership.objects.create(person_a=a, person_b=b)
>>> Partnership.objects.create(person_a=b, person_b=a) # Allowed
```

Is there some class Meta I am missing? Or is there another way to ensure this? (I know I can override the save class, but I'm asking if there is a way to do this without doing that).

Comment: Try `unique_together = ((partner_a, partner_b), (partner_b, partner_a))`

Comment: You need to have it as tuple if field names as strings: `unique_together = ('partner_a', 'partner_b')`

Comment: I believe it makes more sense to have a `ManyToMany` relation from `Person` to itself and declare `Partnership` as the [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) if you really need it.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply.

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) ManyToMany relationships from a model to self must be done asymmetrically. What's more is that this does not actually prevent the asymmetry that I was initially attempting to enforce.